# Loading a mute video with a separate audio into a HTML5 video tag

Tags: html, audio, tags, html5-video, html5-audio

I need to load a mute video and an audio file into the same html5 video tag. I tried to find this, but I only found texts about audio tag, which is not what I am looking for.

I need something like this:

```
<video controls="controls" poster="poster.jpg" width="640" height="360">
  <source src="08_gestao_documental_autoridades_brasileiras_SEM_AUDIO.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="autoridades_brasileiras.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
 </video>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's not how `source` works. The `source` elements are really alternatives: if the browser doesn't support one, it will go to the next, until it reaches one that is supported and played, then only that one will play (and the others will be *ignored*).

You cannot have two sources (a video and an audio) playing at the same time under the same `video`/`audio` tag. As you found online, if you want to have two media elements (the muted video and the audio) you will need two media tags.

Then, and at least in theory (and if I didn't misunderstand), you could use `mediagroup` to control and sync both `audio` and `video` elements so they are streamed together; but `mediagroup` is not well supported... or at least I haven't been able to make it work, but you may want to look into it because, as I said, I may have misunderstood how it works :-S

---

One alternative solution would be to have the `audio` inside the `video` (as the fallback code), then synchronize them using JavaScript. Something like this:

```
<video id="myvideo" controls muted>
    <source src="path/to/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <audio id="myaudio" controls>
        <source src="path/to/audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    </audio>
</video>

<script>
var myvideo = document.getElementById("myvideo");
var myaudio = document.getElementById("myaudio");
myvideo.onplay  = function() { myaudio.play();  }
myvideo.onpause = function() { myaudio.pause(); }
</script>
```

You can [see an example on this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ogmjq5m/).

Comment: Excellent approach but has to be tweaked a little bit. If the video track has no audio, the audio controls will no be available on the UI and therefore cannot be user manipulated. My approach was to disable controls on video and place audio just below it and control video progress from audio controls. all works fine except the full screen icon is not available...thank you for posting this as I have been struggling with multiple sources under video tag for 2 days not knowing there are processed one at a time as fallback...

Comment: Is there any downside of using this method to sync audio and video? I have been searching for a way to do this and your answer is a blessing.

Comment: I guess the <audio> tag doesn't have to be inside the <video> tag. Putting one inside another does not necessarily make them synchronize. In practice, if the network condition is not good, or the files are too large, there is no guarantee that they are synchronized. Even half a second of async will be quite noticeable. To avoid the situation, you'll have to write more javascript to constantly check the progress of the two elements, and adjust they play time to force the synchronization.

Comment: The above approach works well in Chrome but in Safari it does not (desktop and mobile). I've found that Apple is quite restrictive about concurrent playback of multiple media files. The only way I've able to achieve it on Safari is with a video that has no audio track and the muted flag set on it.

Comment: @Eschaton The code above works fine for me on Safari on desktop (12.1.1), but it has the video with muted flag as you mentioned. Let me know what version of Safari you are using so I can run tests.

Comment: YouTube's 1080p video is separate from their audio, I wonder how they serve them both at the same time.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, consider adding a simple seeking method to your example code
`myvideo.onseeking = function() { myaudio.currentTime = myvideo.currentTime; }`

Comment: This solution doesn't work on iOS or on WebOS (TVs), because they only allow one media playing at a time. If you hit play on both, one of them will pause automatically. Does anyone knows any solution for this?